# Inserir dados no banco com php

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando inserir alguns dados no banco via php, mas ele não consegue adicionar esses dados, alguém saberia o que pode ser? dou um var_dump no array para saber se está puxando os dados corretamente e ele está. Estou querendo puxar os dados de uma tabela e mandar para outra. Só isso, caso eu não consiga fazer isso teria como eu salvar esses dados que estou puxando em um arquivo .sql? Como eu faria isso com php?

**Resultado var_dump**

```
    array(27) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Elvis"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "Domingues"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [6]=>
  NULL
  [7]=>
  NULL
  [8]=>
  string(14) "--------------"
  [9]=>
  NULL
  [10]=>
  NULL
  [11]=>
  NULL
  [12]=>
  string(13) "teste apelido"
  [13]=>
  NULL
  [14]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [15]=>
  NULL
  [16]=>
  NULL
  [17]=>
  NULL
  [18]=>
  string(33) "elvis.domingues@----------"
  [19]=>
  NULL
  [20]=>
  NULL
  [21]=>
  string(19) "1979-04-06 00:00:00"
  [22]=>
  string(11) "------------"
  [23]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [24]=>
  NULL
  [25]=>
  NULL
  [26]=>
  NULL
}
Erro ao inserir cliente
```

**Código**

```
   $users = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    $id = $user->getId();

    $usuario_loaded = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);

                $tudo = array(
                $id = $usuario_loaded->getId(),
                $clientes_id = $usuario_loaded->getId(),  
                $nome = $usuario_loaded->getFirstname(),
                $sobrenome = $usuario_loaded->getLastname(),
                $loja = $usuario_loaded->getWebsiteId(),
                $grupo = $usuario_loaded->getGroupId(),
                $prefixo = $usuario_loaded->getPrefix(),
                $assinatura = $usuario_loaded->getMiddlename(),
                $cpf = $usuario_loaded->getCpf(),
                $cnpj = $usuario_loaded->getCnpj(),
                $razao = $usuario_loaded->getCompanyName(),
                $fantasia = $usuario_loaded->getTradingName(),
                $apelido = $usuario_loaded->getNickname(),
                $insestadual = $usuario_loaded->getIe(),
                $tipocadastro = $usuario_loaded->getType(),
                $profissao = $usuario_loaded->getOccupation(),
                $fundação = $usuario_loaded->getFoundationDay(),
                $sufixo = $usuario_loaded->getSuffix(),
                $email = $usuario_loaded->getEmail(),
                $emailsec = $usuario_loaded->getEmailSeconday(),
                $emailfiscal = $usuario_loaded->getEmailBilling(),
                $nascimento = $usuario_loaded->getDob(),
                $cpfcnpj = $usuario_loaded->getTaxvat(),
                $sexo = $usuario_loaded->getGender(),
                $departamento = $usuario_loaded->getDepartment(),
                $ondeconheceu = $usuario_loaded->getHowFindUs(),
                $adyen = $usuario_loaded->getAdyenCustomerRef());  

 var_dump($tudo);

     $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','teste2') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
                $sql = mysqli_query($strcon,
                "INSERT INTO clientes(
                         id
                         clientes_id,
                         nome,
                         sobrenome,
                         loja,
                         grupo,
                         prefixo,
                         assinatura,
                         cpf,
                         cnpj,
                         razao,
                         fantasia,
                         apelido,
                         insestadual,
                         tipocadastro,
                         profissao,
                         fundação,
                         sufixo,
                         email,
                         emailsec,
                         emailfiscal,
                         nascimento,
                         cpfcnpj,
                         sexo,
                         departamento,
                         ondeconheceu,
                         adyen) 
                         VALUES (
                         '$id',
                         '$clientes_id',
                         '$nome',
                         '$sobrenome',
                         '$loja',
                         '$grupo',
                         '$prefixo',
                         '$assinatura',
                         '$cpf',
                         '$cnpj',
                         '$razao',
                         '$fantasia',
                         '$apelido',
                         '$insestadual',
                         '$tipocadastro',
                         '$profissao',
                         '$fundação',
                         '$sufixo',
                         '$email',
                         '$emailsec',
                         '$emailfiscal',
                         '$nascimento',
                         '$cpfcnpj',
                         '$sexo',
                         '$departamento',
                         '$ondeconheceu',
                         '$adyen')");
                        mysqli_query($strcon,
                        $sql) or die("Erro ao inserir cliente \n");
```

Comment: o teu array esta com chaves sequenciais, no insert você esta usando variaveis que pelo que vejo nao estao instanciadas, seria interessante converter seu array nas variaveis corretas ou ajustas as chaves do mesmo para poder usar direto

Comment: Esqueci de colocar as variáveis aqui na pergunta, mas tenho elas no código, descuido meu.

Comment: Você pretende copiar os mesmos dados de uma tabela para outra?

Comment: Sim, seria basicamente isso.. só que eu gostaria de retirar esses dados e colocar novamente em outra tabela, não gostaria de fazer isso por mysql alterando as tabelas..

Comment: Tabela do banco ou tabela da pagina na exibição? Tipo tirar de uma tabela do banco e colocar logo em outra ou ver quer retirar os dados para mostrar na pagina e depois mandar de volta para o banco?

Comment: Tabela do banco, eu puxo os dados dessa tabela (customer/customer) e depois gostaria de inserir esses mesmos dados em outra tabela

Comment: @adventistaam Pode ser qualquer uma das formas, eu gostaria de colocar esses dados em uma outra tabela, mas se não for possível retirar esses dados em um documento para depois eu inseri-los, acho que colocar em outra tabela direto é menos trabalhoso, pois lá vou ter esses mesmos dados.

Comment: Você pode fazer assim:
`INSERT INTO 'tabela2' 
        ( 'codigo','cliente_id','nome', 'sobrenome', 'loja')
         SELECT 'id', 'cliente_id', 'nome', 'sobrenome', 'loja' FROM 'customer' WHERE
         'id' = 1`

Comment: Não funcionou...

Comment: Que erro que deu?

Comment: Comigo funciona.

Comment: A outra forma seria você salvar o objeto direto no insert. Por exemplo: 
`INSERT INTO sua_tabela ( 'codigo', 'cliente_id', etc ) VALUES ( $tudo[0], $tudo[1], etc )`

Comment: Eu consegui aqui agora, era um erro de syntax que eu estava tendo, já consegui corrigir, com base em seus comentarios, muito obrigado @adventistaam

Comment: Essa outra sugestão foi de acordo com o seu var_dump, mas que bom que deu certo

Comment: @adventistaam Sim, agora estou tendo outro erro, pelo cliente usar ' em seu sobrenome, exemplo D'souza da um erro por conta do >'< você já viu algo do tipo?

Comment: Vixe. Já passei por isso, você pusar o [str_replace("'","\'",$cliente);](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solução**

```
    $users = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    $id = $user->getId();

    $usuario_loaded = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);

    $tudo = array('id'=>$usuario_loaded->getId(), 'clientes_id'=>$usuario_loaded->getId(), 'nome'=>$usuario_loaded->getFirstname(), 'sobrenome'=>$usuario_loaded->getLastname(), 'loja'=>$usuario_loaded->getWebsiteId(), 'grupo'=>$usuario_loaded->getGroupId(), 'prefixo'=>$usuario_loaded->getPrefix(), 'assinatura'=>$usuario_loaded->getMiddlename(), 'cpf'=>$usuario_loaded->getCpf(), 'cnpj'=>$usuario_loaded->getCnpj(), 'razao'=>$usuario_loaded->getCompanyName(), 'fantasia'=>$usuario_loaded->getTradingName(), 'apelido'=>$usuario_loaded->getNickname(), 'insestadual'=>$usuario_loaded->getIe(), 'tipocadastro'=>$usuario_loaded->getType(), 'profissao'=>$usuario_loaded->getOccupation(), 'fundação'=>$usuario_loaded->getFoundationDay(), 'sufixo'=>$usuario_loaded->getSuffix(), 'email'=>$usuario_loaded->getEmail(), 'emailsec'=>$usuario_loaded->getEmailSeconday(), 'emailfiscal'=>$usuario_loaded->getEmailBilling(), 'nascimento'=>$usuario_loaded->getDob(), 'cpfcnpj'=>$usuario_loaded->getTaxvat(), 'sexo'=>$usuario_loaded->getGender(), 'departamento'=>$usuario_loaded->getDepartment(), 'ondeconheceu'=>$usuario_loaded->getHowFindUs(), 'adyen'=>$usuario_loaded->getAdyenCustomerRef());


                var_dump($tudo);

                $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                $query = "INSERT INTO clientes (`id`, `clientes_id`, `nome`, `sobrenome`, `loja`, `grupo`, `prefixo`, `assinatura`, `cpf`, `cnpj`, `razao`, `fantasia`, `apelido`, `insestadual`, `tipocadastro`, `profissao`, `fundação`, `sufixo`, `email`, `emailsec`, `emailfiscal`, `nascimento`, `cpfcnpj`, `sexo`, `departamento`, `ondeconheceu`, `adyen`) VALUES ('".$tudo['id']."', '".$tudo['clientes_id']."', '".$tudo['nome']."', '".$tudo['sobrenome']."', '".$tudo['loja']."', '".$tudo['grupo']."', '".$tudo['prefixo']."', '".$tudo['assinatura']."', '".$tudo['cpf']."', '".$tudo['cnpj']."', '".$tudo['razao']."', '".$tudo['fantasia']."', '".$tudo['apelido']."', '".$tudo['insestadual']."', '".$tudo['tipocadastro']."', '".$tudo['profissao']."', '".$tudo['fundação']."', '".$tudo['sufixo']."', '".$tudo['email']."', '".$tudo['emailsec']."', '".$tudo['emailfiscal']."', '".$tudo['nascimento']."', '".$tudo['cpfcnpj']."', '".$tudo['sexo']."', '".$tudo['departamento']."', '".$tudo['ondeconheceu']."', '".$tudo['adyen']."')";
                $connection->query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Segundo comentário `eu puxo os dados dessa tabela (customer/customer) e depois gostaria de inserir esses mesmos dados em outra tabela`

Pode ser feito dessa maneira:

```
$conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "Nome_DB");

    $array = array();   

    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM Nome_Tabela");

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $array[] = $row;
    }               

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $value) {

        $var1 = $array[$i]['NomeColuna1'];
        $var2 = $array[$i]['NomeColuna2'];
        $var3 = $array[$i]['NomeColuna3'];
        .............................
        .............................
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO Nome_Nova_Tabela VALUES ('','$var1','$var2,'$var3', ..........')");
        $i++;

    }

mysqli_close($conn);
```

**Pode simplificar no foreach assim:**

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO Nome_Nova_Tabela VALUES ('', '".$array[$i]['NomeColuna1']."', '".$array[$i]['NomeColuna2']."', '".$array .......)");
    $i++;

}
```

Comment: Já foi resolvido, mas obrigado pelo seu comentário! Por eu usar a plataforma magento esse  `$users = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();` é um método próprio dele de puxar os dados dando os gets `getName();`. Ele tem uma estrutura de tabelas bem diferenciado onde cada tabela guarda uma informação, mas eu puxando desta maneira eu consigo pegar todas as informações que eu preciso. Por isso não dava um select direto na tabela.

Comment: @GustavoSouza no mais acabei aprendendo mais alguma coisa com vc :) Nesse caso vou remover minha resposta. Sei nada de Magento

Comment: Você quem sabe, por ser uma inserção de dados via PHP "puro" a sua pode ajudar outras pessoas, acho que informação nunca é demais, seu código está de fácil entendimento e pode ser que ajude alguém.

Comment: @GustavoSouza ok me convenceu